# Reverse y-axis in boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, reverse

I have read related topics but I still could not figure it out.
I made a boxplot using the following data. 
How to reverse the y-axis in a way that 12 appears at top and 19 appears at bottom of y-axis?

```
 X <- (13,13,13,12,14,14,14,13,16,16,13,15,15,15,14,14,13,16,15,19,15,16,17,14,19,16,18,17,17,18,17,17,19,17,17)
```

I have used `boxplot(X,at=rev(1:nlevels(X)))`, which shows this error: `'at' must have same length as 'z$n', i.e. 1`

Any comment would be great!

Comment: `at=` is for changing positions on the x-axis. You are only plotting one box.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, How I can solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `ylim`:

```
X <- c(13,13,13,12,14,14,14,13,16,16,13,15,15,15,14,14,13,16,15,19,15,16,17,14,19,16,18,17,17,18,17,17,19,17,17)
boxplot(X, ylim = c(19, 12))
```

Produces:

[image: Boxplot with reversed Y axis]

---

Added after comment about switching the y-axis to the right

The code needed to do that:

```
boxplot(X, ylim = c(19, 12), axes=FALSE)
axis(4, pos = 1.3)
```

Produces:

[image: Boxplot y-axis on the right and inverted scale]

Comment: Thank you @jmcastagnetto. how should I put y-axis on the right side, and also closer to the box plot?

Comment: Look at the `axis()` function which allows you to create custom axis for your plot. 
After you got that, you'll need to suppress the regular y-axis in boxplot: `boxplot(X, ylim = c(19, 12), yaxt="n")`or axes and frames: `boxplot(X, ylim = c(19, 12), axes=FALSE)`
Another option is to use `ggplot` with a custom theme and element positions

Answer (score -1):

Or try it the tidyverse way:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(X = c(13,13,13,12,14,14,14,13,16,16,13,15,15,15,14,14,13,16,15,19,15,16,17,14,19,16,18,17,17,18,17,17,19,17,17)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = '', y = X)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  xlab('')
```

[image]